# rails select_tag, how to generate dropdown list with json value and custom text from an array

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, select

I'ved got a json array and i want to create a dropdown selection list. And because its json, i dont want to display json but based on a readable name.

I tried 2 methods that came the closest, but cant get what i want.

controller:

```
@books = [{"code"=>"PA1","name"=>"James","type"=>"Novel"},{"code"=>"PA2","name"=>"John","type"=>"Science"}]
```

### method 1

form.html.erb:

```
<%= select "book", "book", @books.each_with_index.map {|name, index| [name,name["name"]]} %>
```

the generated html:

```
<select id="book_book" name="book[book]"><option code="PA1" name="James" type="Novel" value="James">James</option>
<option code="PA2" name="John" type="Science" value="John">John</option></select></div>
```

### method 2

form.html.erb:

```
<%= select_tag "book", options_for_select(@books) %>
```

the generated html:

```
<select id="book" name="book"><option value="{&quot;code&quot;=&gt;&quot;PA1&quot;,&quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;James&quot;, &quot;type&quot;=&gt;&quot;Novel&quot;}">{&quot;code&quot;=&gt;&quot;PA1&quot;, &quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;James&quot;, &quot;type&quot;=&gt;&quot;Novel&quot;}</option><option value="{&quot;code&quot;=&gt;&quot;PA2&quot;, &quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;John&quot;, &quot;type&quot;=&gt;&quot;Science&quot;}">{&quot;code&quot;=&gt;&quot;PA2&quot;, &quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;John&quot;, &quot;type&quot;=&gt;&quot;Science&quot;}</option></select> </div>
```

### method 3 (update new method not working as well)

Even this does not work, there is 2 different "value"! Getting more frustrated.

```
@books = [{"value" => {"code"=>"PA1","name"=>"James","type"=>"Novel"}},{"value" => {"code"=>"PA2","name"=>"John","type"=>"Science"}}] 

<%= select "book", "book", @books.each_with_index.map {|value, index| [value,value["value"]["name"]]} %></div>

<select id="book_book" name="book[book]"><option value="James" value="{&quot;code&quot;=&gt;&quot;PA1&quot;, &quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;James&quot;, &quot;type&quot;=&gt;&quot;Novel&quot;}">James</option>
<option value="John" value="{&quot;code&quot;=&gt;&quot;PA2&quot;, &quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;John&quot;, &quot;type&quot;=&gt;&quot;Science&quot;}">John</option></select></div>
```

### This is the desired result I want, Please HELP!:

```
 <select id="book_book" name="book[book]"><option value="{"code"=>"PA1","name"=>"James","type"=>"Novel"}">James</option>
<option value="{"code"=>"PA2","name"=>"John","type"=>"Science"}">John</option></select></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why you wanna pass whole hash as string in value of your `<option>`
But if you want to generate this

> ```
> <select id="book_book" name="book[book]"><option value="{"code"=>"PA1","name"=>"James","type"=>"Novel"}">James</option>
> <option value="{"code"=>"PA2","name"=>"John","type"=>"Science"}">John</option></select></div>
> ```

Then you should write following

```
<%= select("book", "book", @books.each.map {|hash| [hash['name'], hash.to_s] }) %></div>
```

Comment: When I submitted the form it sent this `"book"=>{"book"=>"{\"code\"=>\"PA1\", \"name\"=>\"James\", \"type\"=>\"Novel\"}"}`

Comment: thanks... i finally found out the same and infact i wanted to convert it to json, so instead of using .to_s , i converted using .to_json. Well, the reason for this is I store these data in json, postgres has a json datatype, so for me to reconstruct is waste of time, and this would provide an easy way to get the params and insert it right away into the db. thanks.

Comment: OHK! then it's good idea to send it in jason, otherwise I was wondering why someone would send the whole hash back to controller again. :D